# Is this a correct usage of a semicolon?

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

> To my right, was a painting called *Red Blue* and that’s just what it was; a large cobalt blue canvas with a single red stripe painted vertically down the middle.

I've never used a semicolon (at least correctly, *gasp*). My understanding is that semicolons are best used when joining two parts of a sentence that could be sentences separately.

Is this a correct usage?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Some people will probably reply that you _still_ have not used it correctly. Punctuation like this is a _style_ choice: there is nothing grammar-related about it.

Comment: @femmebug, The way you're defining semicolon is correct; the usage is not. In your example sentence, you'd be better served by a colon or a dash (_...that’s just what it was: a large cobalt blue canvas..._).   As it's currently written, the second half of the sentence (after the semicolon) is a fragment and would _not_ work on its own. To use a semicolon, it would need to be something more like _To my right was a painting called **Red Blue** and that’s just what it was; the large cobalt blue canvas had a single red stripe painted vertically down the middle._

Comment: @freeling10 Thank you for this. I wasn't looking closely enough at the second part of my sentence which is, indeed, a fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a colon to connect an introductory statement to a conclusion:

> To my right was a painting called Red Blue, and that’s just what it was: a large cobalt blue canvas with a single red stripe painted vertically down the middle.

I would forget about semicolons, except to separate list items that contain commas; and if you are unsure about using a colon, use a comma instead.

Yay! I used a semicolon.

---

Please note that I hardly ever use semicolons, since most of the time, I am unsure about their usage. However, I noticed that my sentence *could* take a semicolon, and I just couldn't resist it.

Comment: This certainly makes sense. Thank you for explaining. I get anxious about using any type of mid-sentence punctuation beside the good ol' comma. The colon does make sense in this situation though, so thank you.

Comment: @femmebug There's nothing wrong with the humble comma.